# restrict Apache RewriteRule to one forward slash per URL element

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this Apache RewriteRule configured below, which has the problem that it allows the following URL without returning a HTTP 404 error.

http://www.crmpicco.lan/golf/glasgow/play/explore/features/explore/course-features/ayrshire/parkland/

*(this is just a local URL used for development, not publically-accessible)*

```
RewriteRule ^golf/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/$ /golf/?city=$1&golf_region=$2&golf_category=$3 [QSA,L]
```

When I dump out the PHP `$_REQUEST` superglobal, it gives me these values:

```
[url] => golf/
[city] => glasgow/play/explore/features/explore/course-features
[golf_region] => ayrshire
[golf_category] => parkland
```

Notably, the `city` is not correct. What I want to do is only allow one string between the forward-slashes.

Can the RewriteRule be configured to do this?

I am using Apache 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this a shot.

```
RewriteRule ^golf/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/([^.]+)/$ /golf/?city=$1&golf_region=$2&golf_category=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is use of this regex:

```
([^.]+)
```

Which means match text of 1 or more characters until a dot/period is found. You should instead use:

```
([^/]+)
```

Which means match text of 1 or more characters until a forward slash is found.

Your changed rule will be:

```
RewriteRule ^golf/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /golf/?city=$1&golf_region=$2&golf_category=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```